# No wasce version for Java 1.4.2 (WebSphere Application Server 5.1)

Tags: websphere

My company has a web application deployed over WebSphere Application Server version 5.1 (jdk 1.4.2). The company does not want to pay for Rational Software Architect or Rational Application Developer both of which have WebSphere 5.1 servers built into their installers.

I was thinking that my best alternative would be to download a version of WASCE compatible with jdk 1.4.2. However having a look at the versions page for WASCE it doesn't look like there are any versions of it compatible with jdk 1.4.2.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=2359&uid=swg27006834

Am I right? Was WASCE only released for Java 5 onwards?

Don't really want to use another application container to deploy the files because we need to test websphere configurations, environment variables etc.

Can anyone think of any other alternatives if WASCE does not support Jdk 1.4.2?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all WAS CE has a completely different code base compared to other WAS editions (WAS Base, WAS ND etc.). It is based on open source technologies like Apache Geronimo, so you should not be using WAS CE to mimic your WAS 5.1 environment (at sum these are two different servers altogether, only brand name is common).

Main point when running Enterprise Java Applications on application servers is Java EE specification levels, not JRE version. WAS 5.1 supports J2EE 1.2 and 1.3. To determine which one you are using, you shall examine your deployment descriptors (application.xml / web.xml files). Then check [Specifications and API documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rovr_specs.html) at infocenter;

- WAS 6.1 supports J2EE 1.2, 1.3 and 1.4
- WAS 7 support J2EE 1.3, 1.4 and Java EE 5

So if your application is J2EE 1.2 you can use WAS 6.1, and if it is J2EE 1.3 you can use WAS 7. Unfortunately you can't use a newer version of WAS before you migrate your project to a higher specification level (infocenter contains information on how to do that). I strongly suggest you do so because WAS 5.1 is out of support and even WAS 6.1 will be out of support this year.

As per Java SE version, you don't have a problem, your Java SE 1.4 compiled code will run on Java SE 5 and 6 JRE's because of backward compatibility of byte code. Of course if you upgrade your project to later J2EE specifications, you may use a more recent JRE; just compile your migrated project with a newer SDK (there is a little catch though; moving from 1.4 to 5 Java had some new keywords like `enum`, so you must check your code to make sure you don't use these as variable names).

For some time WebSphere has a [Developers Edition](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/developer/). You can add this as a free WAS test server to your eclipse; at sum, if you are lucky and your project is J2EE 1.3 and not 1.2 you can use WAS 7.0 with this setup.

> Use the no-charge WebSphere Application Server Developer Tools for
>   Eclipse (WDT) to develop applications for WAS V7.0, V8.0, V8.5
>   including the Liberty profile. WDT is a subset of Rational Application
>   Developer that can be installed on top of your existing Eclipse
>   environment.

Comment: Thanks for that advice. It has helped me a lot. We are using J2EE Application 1.3 so WAS 7 should suite my needs. I have downloaded WDT and installed over the top of Spring STS. Got question though. Is this a traditional WAS type server? I'm asking because I cannot find startserver.bat, stopserver..bat etc etc

Comment: [WebSphere Application Server for Developers V7](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247913.html) RedBook has step by step description on how to setup your environment, beginning from download to creating profiles. Just follow chapter 1 and you shall be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have a difficult time trying to find any version of WAS that runs on Java 1.4 (other than WAS 5.1).

What is your license aggreement with IBM like? I know that on my current project, we can have local WAS servers running on our own machines to do development work for free. Once we use a server as a shared environment (like a shared test or staging) then we need to purchase a new license. That may be the most reasonable path to take if you don't want to pay for more licensing or can't move to a newer version of WAS yet.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. We haven't asked them about developer licenses yet. I do feel more comfortable now that I can suggest something like what you have described above to my management.